# Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder. Footer is there but not accessable to change heigiht

Tags: sql, reporting-services, footer, reportbuilder3.0

In My Microsoft SQL Report Builder, the footer is inaccessible for any editing and I believe it may be because the height is set to 0 but have no idea how I can change this. I can tell the footer is on because a small dotted line appears when I click add footer. But have no clue how to change the size.

[image: Footer Removed]

[image: Footer Added]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the page footer added (dotted line visible,) slowly move your mouse from the background below to the page pixel by pixel until the cursor turns into the up and down arrows. If you go slow enough, you should be able to grab the footer handle without the page handle, then click and pull down to expand the footer. You can tell if you are in the right spot because the black bar on the ruler to the left will be beneath the gray bar that denotes the end of the page. It helps if you lower your mouse sensitivity.

[image: Scrrencap]
Sorry for poor quality, had to use step recorder to get the cursor. Notice the black bar to the left is below the gray horizontal bar. This means I am over the footer and not the page.

Comment: Also try zooming in to select that elusive footer